# Why is Heroku suddenly rendering garbage for my site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Has anyone ever pushed something to Heroku (that looks and acts FINE locally) and seen this in the browser?

��� V�Zms�6��*��f�vr��KVb�&�4m��M�����Y���X����[ E��ԝ�$��X�.vI�~�짋�w��  2Y��N���� 8-�� �L&�FP�/hL����[�F�����J���`�ؼ��Ǜx��/�˷�9��U�����>�"O��g7�|�.wf�h��4�H*sr���<    �Qp�?�hP5��m�L��l4��   ���k�{ż�@UYMJ(��R9�8��P����x5O���r1*����$IB�h���U|W�((HB�lTł(���F�sRe��Q �%J.ɍ�4��&�b��#�� �p���p�V���$�r��ֳ�xO�x��}��?.\��:��8J6�8Lfq�i�s2_���|ϗQ�<9^�*%�帹G��x���I�����r�$�4��"X/��͜}���qE7�.�k�^�,��d����x� �I2[����*����8P���T�$��}U���C�Ȥ,O&���:sS7j   �-�,�fG��ʂ� ʴ�Cs=4s)ru��|�(i�L��+�����T;��fȇ�!�5?l���/N�SIأ7��ǋ0��<?e�Ӊ���O����S�A��f���2��1Z!

The last push I made I didn't change any assets or views.  I didn't enable any kind of encryption (adding SSL, etc.), didn't change any initializer, didn't add any gem, literally I changed two controllers to refactor some code - these controllers have nothing to do with the login page.

Comment: tyler, something like this would happen to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your header (in `layouts/application.html.erb`):

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - it was the Rack::Deflater middleware config I added to production.rb (multiple deploys back, I must have never hit the server after the initial deploy).  Heroku has their own gem for deflating stuff and serving it compressed.